# Convert pixel coordinates to offset_height offset_width

Tags: css, image-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to crop an image using

```
 tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image,
offset_height,
offset_width,
target_height,
target_width)
```

function in tensorflow. I am having pixel coordinates to crop as x1, y1, x2, y2. How to convert this coordinates to offset_height, offset_width, target_height, target_width

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to convert from points to length?

```
offset_height = y1; //y1 - 0
offset_width = x1; //x1 - 0
target_height = y2 - y1;
target_width = x2 - x1;
```